# In The Walking Dead, how is Herschel walking without crutches?

Tags: the-walking-dead

Herschel can be seen walking without crutches towards the end of S04E01.  Does he have a wooden leg?

Comment: I noticed that hershel was walking without crutches in the later episodes of season 4. I didn't notice it earlier... and I was like omg like what the heckk!

Answer (score 17):

He has a prosthetic leg now.  When he kneels down to talk to Rick in their new farm, you can see it.

[image: screenshot of Herschel's new leg]

Comment: That is some wonderful commitment to detail. Thanks Walking Dead. Thanks.

Comment: -1, needs hand-drawn circle ;-)

Answer (score 5):

[image]There is also a scene in that same episode where we see Herchels prosthetic on the floor and then the camera pans up so we see Herschel scratching his stump! it is around 40.07